# Docker and Postgres - server closed the connection unexpectedly error when using port other than 5432

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I am having this weird error using Postgres with Docker. So, I have two services in my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123

  test-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5433:5433'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
```

So, when I run "docker-compose up -d", both containers get mounted. The command "docker ps" gives me:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                 NAMES
a76fcc56f928   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp             nodejs-nest_iluvcoffe_db_1
9ab54557063f   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5433/tcp, :::5433->5433/tcp   nodejs-nest_iluvcoffe_test-db_1
```

When i try to connect to the container mapping the port 5432->5432, is all good. But when i try to connect to the container mapping the port 5433->5433 I get the error:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

But, if I map the ports like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123

  test-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
```

Then, I will have in my "docker ps":

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
5228461a2cff   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   nodejs-nest_iluvcoffe_db_1
39353d05004c   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp   nodejs-nest_iluvcoffe_test-db_1
```

And I can connect to both containers/postgres-servers. Someone know why that? why I cant use the 5433->5433 ports mapping?

Answer (score 5):

I believe i understood what is happening. Inside the container, by default, postgres will run on port 5432, even if i map on the ports directive:

```
ports:
      - '5433:5433'
```

To tell postgres which port to run inside the container, i used the setup below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123

  test-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5433:5433'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
    command: -p 5433
```

And everything is working now

Answer (score 3):

- `Postgresql` service listens on port `5432` within your container.
- `ports` section with `5433->5432` means `map host port 5433 to listening container port 5432`

  > As a result, mapping 5433 on 5433 is not possible without changing port listening inside postgresql container.
- Each container is like a single host, modifying listening port **within** `posgresql container` should not be necessary.

Please check this documentation for more information on postgresql default settings :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html